# JTable and Iterate Bound ObservableList

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable

I have a JTables that are bound to ObservableList.  T are beans that are generated from my webservice.

So my questions is, how can I iterate the bound list from the table instance.  getModel() is "org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding$BindingTableModel"

The idea is:

((ObservableList)table.getModel()).foreach(...

Comment: `com.jgoodies.binding.list.ObservableList`?

Comment: Does this mean your table has only one column (or how else could it be represented by a list). And why do you need to have access to that `ObservableList`. If you just want to loop over all elements (as in the code you posted), the `TableModel` API is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

A TableModel is a TableModel is a TableModel regardless of the ultimate concrete class that extends it. Like all TableModels, you can call the interface methods of `getRowCount()`, `getColumnCount()`, and `getValueAt(...)` to allow you to iterate through your table and extract your values.

Here is a link to an [API for the BindingTableModel](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/beansbinding/beansbinding/1.2.1/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingbinding/JTableBinding%24BindingTableModel.class?classDetails=ok)

It looks to implement TableModel but does not extend AbstractTableModel or DefaultTableModel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was though looking to get the actual instance of the ObservableList.  The value I am looking for is not currently bound to the table but does exist in the underlaying list.  I could bind the value to the table and do as you suggest.  I was hoping there was an efficient way of doing this.  Thanks